# Java mean of elapsed time

Tags: java, mean, elapsedtime

I am trying to calculate the mean of all elapsed times in my loop. Can anyone help me out? My issue is I am unsure how to use the total time of all of the loops to calculate the mean.

```java
package ClassOne;

import java.util.Random;

public class SelectionProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000;j++) {
        
        double startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Random rd = new Random();
        int [] n = new int [100];
        for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            n[i] = rd.nextInt();
        }
        
        SelectionSort(n);
        printArray(n);
        double endTime = System.nanoTime();
        
        double elapsedTime = endTime-startTime; 
        System.out.println("  Elapsed Time:" + elapsedTime);
        }
    }
    
    public static int[] SelectionSort(int[] A) {
        
            int k;
            int temp;
        
            for (int i=0; i<A.length-1; i++) {
                k=i;
                for (int j=i+1; j<=A.length-1; j++) {
                    if (A[j]<A[k]) {
                        k=j;
                    }
                }
            
                temp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[k];
                A[k] = temp;
            }
            return A;
        }

    public static void printArray(int[] A) {
        for(int i = 0; i<A.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(A[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *tried a few options out for calculating the mean and non of them have worked* - show us what you have tried.  Is it not better to learn why something you have tried does not work?

Comment: BTW why is `double startTime = System.nanoTime();` in your loop?  This code would not even compile.

Comment: If what you want to do is time `SelectionSort` then you shouldn't be including initialising the array with random numbers or printing the result in your timing.

Comment: to calculate the elapsed time. Should I move it above the for loop?

Comment: So the "mean"is the average, then that would mean you need the total value divided by number elements, so you'd need the "total time" divided by the "total number of iterations"

Comment: my issue is i am not sure how I can get the total time of each loop

Comment: Use a `long` to accumulate the elapsed nanos, with a variable such as `totalNanos` defined outside the loop.  Then each iteration of the loop, add the elapsed nanos to the `totalNanos`.  Finally, after the loop ends, divide `totalNanos` by the number of loop iterations (10000 in the example).

Comment: Also, the tracking of elapsed nanos within an iteration should only be around the call to `SelectionSort(n)`, otherwise the elapsed time will include the set up time and the `printArray(n)` time.

Comment: yes it's supposed to include everything

Comment: @AndrewS so when I set up the long I make it long totalNanos = (what do I put in here);?

Comment: initialize to 0

Comment: Properly format code posted here. Either wrap in a pair of triple back-ticks, or indent all of it by four spaces. And clean up your code before posting, such as deleting the many excessive blank lines. I fixed your post this time today.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thank you for the help and advice. This was my first post on here.

Answer (score 1):

Start your timing with:

```
long startNanos= System.nanoTime() ;
```

Notice that `System.nanoTime()` returns a `long`, not the `double` seen in your code.

End your timing with:

```
Duration elapsed = Duration.ofNanos( System.nanoTime() - startNanos ) ;
```

Make a list to track multiple durations.

```
List< Duration > elapsedDurations = new ArrayList <> () ;
```

Add each duration.

```
elapsedDurations.add( elapsed ) ;
```

Loop the elements of that list to calculate the mean.

```java
long totaNanos = 0 ;
for( Duration d : elapsedDurations )
{
    totaNanos = ( totaNanos + d.toNanos() ) ;
}
long meanNanos = ( totaNanos / elapsedDurations.size() ) ;
```

Or, let the Java libraries do the heavy lifting for you. Calculate the mean by way of a [`LongSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LongSummaryStatistics.html) object.

```java
LongSummaryStatistics stats =
    elapsedDurations
        .stream()
        .mapToLong( Duration :: toNanos )
        .summaryStatistics();

//stats.getSum()
//stats.getCount() 
//stats.getMax() 
//stats.getMin() 
Duration mean = Duration.ofNanos( stats.getAverage() ) ;
```